# save output into a file from sqlplus query in ksh script

Tags: shell, files, sqlplus

The thing is that it overwrites in Result.txt and I only get the last query. How can I fix this?

```
#!/bin/sh
while read -r line
do
  echo "'$line'"
  sqlplus -s whatever/whatever <<-EOF
  SPOOL Result.txt
  SELECT * FROM ---- WHERE sol = '$line';
  SPOOL OFF ;   
  exit;
EOF

done < evs.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

just add

```
 rm Results.txt
```

before the loop

and

```
 cat Result.txt >> Results.txt
```

after EOF (and before `done`).

Comment: Thanks but now there is sth wierd happening, now I get "no rows selected" in Results.txt and in the shell I get    


cat: Resultado3.txt: Source is same as Target. Skipping...

Comment: "No Row selected" means query return no row. have you typed cat as mention in my answer ?